# Effects of Killing an Enderdragon in Minecraft SMP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the effect of killing the enderdragon in smp?

I've been told that endermen disappear if you kill the enderdragon in ssp, does that also apply to smp?

If somebody does kill the enderdragon, then is there any way to get a new one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the credits, 20,000 XP, and a fountain through which you can return to the normal world.

The Endermen do stay there.

Depending on the server mods installed, you can get a new Enderdragon using the `/spawn` command.

Comment: As an addendum, I've been informed from reliable parties that deleting the_end folder in vanilla smp does not create a new dragon, so really there's only one dragon per world, forever. (barring mods)

Comment: unless you generate it in SSP and copy it :D